# Three.js - Put two materials on the same object

Tags: three.js, shader

I was wondering how to put two materials on the same object...
I have a shader material that I use for the colors, but I also want to have a basing lambert shading.

Here is the code :

```
var material1 = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent
} );

var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
});

var materials = [material1, material2];

var group = new THREE.Object3D();   
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you not just set the color on the lambert shader? To set multiple materials to a single mesh you could use MeshFaceMaterial but that does not overlay them like it sounds like you want. It really sounds like you just want to add lambert shading to your own custom shader, which should not be too hard.

Comment: @2pha That's exactly what I want. I found a GLSL tutorial about lambert shading, but it used a light created in the shader code. I don't know how to use "global lighting". Anyway, here it is : https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/lighting.php

Comment: A good way to start is to take a look at how the materials in three.js are put together. You can see it in [ShaderLib.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js).  
The actual shader chunks are [HERE](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk). [My own shaderMaterial experiments](http://blog.2pha.com/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial) may help you.

Comment: @2pha I already knew you shaderMaterial experiments, my fragment shader is based on your "Uv position color" experiment which gave me this nice look like height map : http://grab.by/N5Oa . I will try to add the lamber shading from three.js , but it seems very long compared to my existing shader

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/nrz5p3xp/2/) is a fiddle that shows how to incorporate the lambert chuck into your own shader.
Is this what you wanted?
It calculates in the vertex shader the same as the THREE.MeshLambertMaterial.

```
var myShader = {
    uniforms : THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([
    THREE.UniformsLib['lights'],
    {
        color : {type:"c", value:new THREE.Color(0x0000ff)}
    }
  ]),
  vertexShader : [
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "common" ],
    'varying vec3 vLightFront;',
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lights_lambert_pars_vertex" ],
    'void main() {',
    '  vec3 transformedNormal = normalMatrix * normal;',
    '  vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lights_lambert_vertex" ],
    '  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;',
    '}'
  ].join('\n'),
  fragmentShader : [
    'uniform vec3 color;',
    'varying vec3 vLightFront;',
    'void main() {',
    '  vec3 outgoingLight = color.rgb + vLightFront;',
    '  gl_FragColor = vec4(outgoingLight, 1.0);',
    '}',
  ].join('\n'),
};

    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms : myShader.uniforms,
      vertexShader : myShader.vertexShader,
      fragmentShader : myShader.fragmentShader,
      lights: true
    });
```